# Extending HtmlHelper for Kendo DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have written a htmlhelper extension method for text boxes and dropdown list in mvc and c# projects and currently I am using the Kendo UI and have used the controls provided by Kendo for Dropdownlist and Textbox.

I have tried using the same approach as in MVC

```
    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_DropDownList(this  HtmlHelper helper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list)
    {
        return Custom_DropDownList(helper, name, list);
    }
```

but I can't expose the above helper method with kendo dropdown. I know, this is wrong and I have been struggling with that.

I am populating the dropdown values from database and in addition to the current values in the list, 
I would like to

- append one blank row at the top of list
- or (ALL) option at the top of the list (when there are more than one values),
- (ALL) will not be displayed if the dropdown has only one value.

In case anyone has implemented the dropdown helper methods in kendo, is requested to share the idea or suggest me a way to get around this.

**EDIT**

using custom htmlhelper for normal dropdownlist, we do like this

```
public static MvcHtmlString StateDropDownList(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    return html.TextBox("foo");
}
```

and then we can use this htmlhelper in the code.

How to achieve the same code for Kendo().DropDownList() as I haven't seen any example doing so, neither, I don't knpw, how Kendo dropdownlist parses the html internally. I tried to do something like below, but I unable to find the solution

```
public static MvcHtmlString Custom_DropdownList(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list, string option, object htmlAttributes)
{
      var divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
      divTag.AddCssClass("k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset");
      divTag.Attributes.Add("id", "ddlMemType-list");
      divTag.Attributes.Add("data-role", "popup");
      divTag.Attributes.Add("style", "position: absolute; height: auto; display: none;");

      TagBuilder ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");

      ulTag.Attributes.Add("id", "ddlMemType_listbox");
      ulTag.MergeAttribute("unselectable", "on");
      ulTag.AddCssClass("k-list k-reset");
      ulTag.MergeAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
      ulTag.MergeAttribute("role", "listbox");
      ulTag.MergeAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
      ulTag.MergeAttribute("aria-live", "off");
      ulTag.MergeAttribute("style","overflow: auto;");
      ulTag.InnerHtml += Environment.NewLine;

      foreach (var item in list)
      {
            var liTag = new TagBuilder("li");
            liTag.MergeAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
            liTag.MergeAttribute("role", "option");
            liTag.MergeAttribute("unselectable", "on");
            liTag.AddCssClass("k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused");
            liTag.Attributes.Add("id", "ddlMemType_option_selected");
            liTag.MergeAttribute("aria-selected", "true");

            ulTag.InnerHtml += string.Format("  {0}{1}{2}", liTag.ToString(), item.Text, Environment.NewLine);
       }
       divTag.InnerHtml += string.Format("{0}{1}", ulTag.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
       return MvcHtmlString.Create(divTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you're trying to do? I don't understand what you are asking. I have done something like this so if you can provide better details I can probably answer your question.

Comment: @MailmanOdd: Let me provide you an example of what I want to do, for your reference. See EDIT. Thanks

Comment: I used your code and made my own to TextBoxFor... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172261/extend-kendo-htmlhelpers-for-textboxfor

Answer (score 1):

Though it is an old question, this answer can be useful:

```
public static MvcHtmlString StateDropDownList(this HtmlHelper html)
{
   if ( <textbox display condition>)
    return html.TextBox("foo");
   else 
     return html.DropDownList("ddlId", selectList, htmlAttributes)
}
For this you just need to write below in Script part of .cshtml

<script type="text/javascript">
      $("ddlId").kendoDropDownList();
</script>
```